# linear regression: my plotting doesn't show the line

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, plot, linear-regression

I am working on implementing from scratch a linear regression model means without using Sklearn package.

all was working just fine , until i tried ploting the result.

my fit line isn't showing:[image: this is what it shows]

**i looked at a bunch of solution but neither of them was for myy problem**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Salary.csv')

x=data['Salary']

y=data['YearsExperience']


#y= mx+b

m = 0
b = 0

Learning_Rate = .01
epochs = 5000

n = np.float(x.shape[0])
error = []

for i in range(epochs):
   Y_hat = m*x+b

#error
   mse= (1/n)*np.sum((y-Y_hat)**2)
   error.append(mse)

#gradient descend
   db = (-2/n) * np.sum(x*(y-Y_hat))
   dm = (-2/n) * np.sum((y-Y_hat))

   m = m - Learning_Rate * dm
   b = b - Learning_Rate * db

#tracing x and y line
x_line = np.linspace(0, 15, 100)
y_line = (m*x_line)+ b



#ploting result
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))

plt.title('LR result')
**plt.plot(x_line,y_line) #the problem is apparently here
                        # i just don't know what to do**
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

appart from that, there is no problem with the code .

Comment: Please turn off the warnings filter, look at the output/final value of `x_line` and `y_line` and you will see what's making pyplot unable to plot the line.

Comment: x_line is just fine , i think the problem with y_line

Comment: @Walid For a start, you should remove that horrible line `warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')`. You should replace `np.float` by `float`, as indicated by the warning.  Then, you should test your code with just a few epochs, e.g. 10.  You should also start to debug your `for` loop, e.g. by printing the values of `m` and `b` at each step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has multiple problems:

- you are plotting the line from `0` and `15`, while data range from about `40000` to `140000`. Even if you are correctly computing the line, you are going to plot it in a region far away from your data
- in the loop there is a mistake in the computation of `dm` and `db`, they are swapped. The corrected expressions are:

  ```
  dm = (-2/n)*np.sum(x*(y - Y_hat))
  db = (-2/n)*np.sum((y - Y_hat))
  ```
- your `x` and `y` data are on very different scales: `x` is `~10⁴` magnitude, while `y` is `~10¹`. For this reason, also `m` and `b` will likely be very different from each other (different orders of magnitude). This is the reason why you should use two different learning rate for the different quantities you are optimizing: `Learning_Rate_m` for `m` and `Learning_Rate_b` for `b`
- finally, the [gradient descent method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) is strongly affected by the initial guess: it may lead to find local minima (fake solutions) in place of the global minima (true solution). For this reason, you should try with different initial guesses for `m` and `b`, possibly close to their estimated value:

  ```
  m = 0
  b = -2
  ```

### Complete Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


N = 40
np.random.seed(42)
x = np.random.randint(low = 38000, high = 145000, size = N)
y = (13 - 1)/(140000 - 40000)*(x - 40000) + 1 + 0.5*np.random.randn(N)


# initial guess
m = 0
b = -2

Learning_Rate_m = 1e-10
Learning_Rate_b = 1e-2
epochs = 5000

n = np.float(x.shape[0])
error = []


for i in range(epochs):
   Y_hat = m*x + b

   mse = 1/n*np.sum((y - Y_hat)**2)
   error.append(mse)

   dm = -2/n*np.sum(x*(y - Y_hat))
   db = -2/n*np.sum((y - Y_hat))

   m = m - Learning_Rate_m*dm
   b = b - Learning_Rate_b*db


x_line = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
y_line = (m*x_line) + b


plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))

plt.title('LR result')
plt.plot(x_line,y_line, 'red')

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

### Plot

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, now that I looked at your answer. I know what I need to do.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not happening while plotting, the problem is with the parameters in plt.plot(x_line,y_line), I tested your code and found that y_line is all NaN values, double check the calculations (y_line, m, dm).

Comment: I really don't know

Comment: how should I do then, I used the math formula technically

Comment: Can you give me the source where you got these from ? 


`
`for i in range(epochs):

   Y_hat = m*x+b

#error
   mse= (1/n)*np.sum((y-Y_hat)**2)
   error.append(mse)

#gradient descend
   db = (-2/n) * np.sum(x*(y-Y_hat))
   dm = (-2/n) * np.sum((y-Y_hat))

   m = m - Learning_Rate * dm
   b = b - Learning_Rate * db`

Comment: it was on a youtube video, from stat quest Chanel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).